# why my Django blog admin interface don't have "blog posts "and 'sites'

Tags: django, interface, blogs

Following online tutorial, I create a very simple django blog. It seems all right, but after I log into  127.0.0.1:8000/admin/ , **I can't find the place to add posts.**

**My django blog interface**(I don't have enough reputation to add picture):

---

**Django administration**

Welcome,xxx  change password / log out

**Site administration**

Authentication and Authorization
Groups Add Change
Users Add Change

**Recent Actions**
My Actions
None available.

---

**Does anyone know why my administration interface don't have "add post"???  thanks in advance!!   :)**

I use:

Django 1.7
Operation: win 7 32

Answer (score 2):

Seems like you haven't registered your posts model in the Django admin

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/intro/tutorial02/#make-the-poll-app-modifiable-in-the-admin

or your posts app isn't installed in your settings.py
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/intro/tutorial01/#activating-models

And the sites framework is no longer activated by default since Django 1.6

Comment: Note : If the post app is not installed, the `makemigrations` command would not do anything. So if `makemigrations` showed activity other than "No  changes detected", your app is installed.

Answer (score 0):

add `admin.autodiscover()` at `urls.py`. details here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/